# How to count specific values from another table with update query in ms-access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using ms-access, and I have two tables like this:

```
tbl1: contract

| c_ssn | m_ssn | termination |
===============================
|   1   |   1   |      Y      |
|   2   |   2   |      N      |
|   3   |   1   |      Y      |

tbl2: member

| m_ssn | count |
=================
|   1   |       |
|   2   |       |
```

I want to count the number of rows of [ contract ] that the value of [ termination ] is "Y" grouped by [ m_ssn ]. So the desired result will be like this:

```
tbl2: member

| m_ssn | count |
=================
|   1   |   2   |
|   2   |   0   |
```

To do this I've tried this sql code:

```
update member
set count =
(select count(*) from contract
where contract.m_ssn = member.m_ssn & contract.termination = "Y")
```

But this code make the error: "Operation must be an updateable query."
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    m.m_ssn,
    SUM(IIF(c.termination = 'Y', 1, 0)) AS count
FROM member m
LEFT JOIN contract c
    ON m.m_ssn = c.m_ssn
GROUP BY
    m.m_ssn;
```

Note that I recommend against doing the update, because every time the data in the `contract` table changes, you will have to do the update again.  IMO doing the update only makes sense if this is a one-time event.

Comment: It helped a lot. **Thanks :)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using string concatenation where you want the boolean `AND`:

```
update member
set count = (select count(*)
             from contract
             where contract.m_ssn = member.m_ssn and
                   contract.termination = "Y"
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common way to do multiple table update in Access.

```
UPDATE member AS A
INNNER JOIN contract AS B ON A.m_ssn = B.m_ssn 
SET A.count = Count(B.termination)
WHERE B.termination = "Y"
```